# protractor Interaction with Windows Dialog box

Tags: protractor

I need to work with windows dialogue box, but I can't find any information about it.
I have a C# code that I need to rewrite on protractor:

```
ClickOn(Element(Map.DropZone));
WaintUntilElementIsDisplayed(driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement());
Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\Files\JohnSmithAndSons.jpg");
Sleep(500);
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
WaitUntilElementIsVisible(Map.ImagePreview);
```

I can capture this windows form, but I don't what to do next, and I didn't find any information:

```
 mapDropZone.click();
 browser.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Comment: this is a page screen - http://prntscr.com/jpzek3

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ demouser123 - I need to add image name in opened windows form and click 'Open' button

Comment: That is a windows dialogue box - it's something that cannot be automated with any Webdriver based solution like Protractor.

Comment: @ demouser123 ok, but what about this solution on C#: SendKeys.SendWait(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\Files\JohnSmithAndSons.jpg"); Sleep(500); SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");